# How to distinguish points scatter matplotlib on pick

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have two pandas dataframes, `data1` and `data2`

They are shown on the graph. I can click on the point to show the information on this point. But only from one dataset. How to use it for both datasets?
Also I need to show information from another array accessing to the data by index.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show

import pandas as pd
# I want to show infrotmation from these dataframes data using indexes on click
initial_data1 = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")
initial_data2 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv")

data1 = initial_data1.copy()
data2 = initial_data2.copy()

data1 = SomeProcessing(data1) #I use this data to make a plot
data2 = SomeProcessing(data2) #I use this data to make a plot

def showScatter():
    def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        display(initial_data2.loc[ind])

    fig = figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    col = ax1.scatter(data1[:,0], data1[:,1], picker=True)
    col = ax1.scatter(data2[:,0], data2[:,1], marker="+", color = 'black', picker=True)
for i in range(len(data2)):
        ax1.annotate(i, (data2[i,0], data2[i,1]))

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
    show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would use the `event.artist` to determine which artist in the axes the given index `event.ind` belongs to. Then this artist can be used to determine what to do further.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def showScatter(data, otherdata):
    def onpick(event):
        ind = event.ind[0]
        artist = event.artist
        d = otherdata[scatters.index(artist)]
        ax.set_title("You clicked {}".format(d[ind]))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    scatters = []

    for d in data:
        sc = ax.scatter(d[:,0], d[:,1], picker=True)
        scatters.append(sc)
        for i in range(len(d)):
            ax.annotate(i, (d[i,0], d[i,1]), xytext=(0,3),
                        textcoords="offset points", ha="center", va="baseline")

    return fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)


x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(6))
ind = np.random.randint(0,2,size=6*10).astype(bool)
data1 = np.column_stack((x.flatten()[ind], y.flatten()[ind]))
data2 = np.column_stack((x.flatten()[~ind], y.flatten()[~ind]))
cid = showScatter((data1, data2), (data1, data2))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how to get an index for the initial data array?

Comment: What is "the initial data array"? In the answer above you index the array that belongs to the point you clicked on. If you clicked on a blue point, it will use the index to index the array of the blue points, same for orange.

Comment: I understand it. The problem is that I need this index for another array. I do some transformations on it and show the scatter. On click I want to show information from the initial array. I´m sorry for unclear explanation and will edit the question.

Comment: It's not clear from the question how `initial_data` relates to any of `data1` or `data2`.

Comment: Well, I can't know what `SomeProcessing` does. But suppose it leaves the order and length of the data unchanged, you would just supply the inital data to the function as well and use it where you need it. I updated the answer (taking the same data for both).

Comment: Now I understand it. Index actually is present. Thank you, everything is working and working perfect!